# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

am getting can not find resource bundle exception while starting my application. the paths in jsps are fine but still it is throwing the exception
using server JBOSS AS7.2 Alpha , JSF2.0

stack trace

13:06:10,686 INFO  org.jboss.as.server (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "csaEARDev.ear"
13:06:34,580 INFO  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)   ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logError:190)  - 2012/07/19 13:06:34.515: ResponseHeaderFilter : ERROR : :doFilter Exception - Exception[org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en] root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en

> 13:06:34,581 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en
>
> 13:06:34,581 INFO  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6)   ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (com.csc.fs.logging.Log4JHandler:logError:190)  - 2012/07/19 13:06:34.515: ResponseHeaderFilter : ERROR : :doFilter Exception - Exception[org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en] root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en
>
> 13:06:34,581 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
>
> 13:06:34,582 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
>
> 13:06:34,582 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
>
> 13:06:34,582 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>
> 13:06:34,582 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>
> 13:06:34,583 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>
> 13:06:34,583 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840)
>
> 13:06:34,583 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622)
>
> 13:06:34,584 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560)
>
> 13:06:34,585 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
>
> 13:06:34,585 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:542)
>
> 13:06:34,585 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:355)
>
> 13:06:34,586 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:130)
>
> 13:06:34,586 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
>
> 13:06:34,586 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>
> 13:06:34,586 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>
> 13:06:34,586 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
>
> 13:06:34,587 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>
> 13:06:34,587 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>
> 13:06:34,587 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.csc.fs.accel.ui.filters.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:82)
>
> 13:06:34,587 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>
> 13:06:34,587 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>
> 13:06:34,588 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>
> 13:06:34,588 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>
> 13:06:34,588 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397)
>
> 13:06:34,588 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:156)
>
> 13:06:34,588 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>
> 13:06:34,589 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>
> 13:06:34,589 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>
> 13:06:34,589 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>
> 13:06:34,589 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>
> 13:06:34,590 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
>
> 13:06:34,590 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
>
> 13:06:34,590 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> 13:06:34,590 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en
>
> 13:06:34,591 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
>
> 13:06:34,591 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
>
> 13:06:34,591 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
>
> 13:06:34,591 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.LoadBundleTag.doStartTag(LoadBundleTag.java:164)
>
> 13:06:34,591 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jsp.init.aboutForm_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005floadBundle_005f0(aboutForm_jsp.java:270)
>
> 13:06:34,592 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jsp.init.aboutForm_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005fform_005f0(aboutForm_jsp.java:190)
>
> 13:06:34,592 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jsp.init.aboutForm_jsp._jspx_meth_f_005fview_005f0(aboutForm_jsp.java:148)
>
> 13:06:34,592 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jsp.init.aboutForm_jsp._jspService(aboutForm_jsp.java:111)
>
> 13:06:34,592 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>
> 13:06:34,592 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>
> 13:06:34,593 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>
> 13:06:34,593 ERROR org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name properties.ApplicationDetails, locale en (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2)           ... 33 more

Could u suggest if something else needs to be set or what ? why cant it find the bundles at the specified path even if they are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error was because ,a resource bundle

> ApplicationDetails 
>   Was not on classpath.

I packaged that in

> WEB-INF\classes

And it worked.